# Google chrome: an error has occurred download interrupted

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

My friend has windows 10, 64 bit, HP, latest update. He has google chrome latest version and he tried reinstalling it many times. His computer isn't infected with malware as far as malwarebytes and avira can tell. His internet is fast and he had this problem ever since upgrading to windows 10 long time ago.

Whenever he tries to download a chrome extension from chrome's webstore, he gets this.

[image]

As you can see, no logs no details. How to fix? On youtube, they say to use a third party website to download extensions. But I'm looking for a fix, I don't a way to get around it. I want to know how this is fixed once and for all.

He tried cleaning cache and changing the download folder, didn't work

Comment: Have they tried reinstalling the Google Chrome web browser by chance?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove yes i said that in the question

Comment: Doh! My apologies. Have they tried clearing their Chrome cache?

Comment: @mr he tried cleaning cache and changing download folder, nothing worked

Comment: Have them try the Chrome cleanup tool: https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/index.html

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove he tried it and tried installing google chrome canari too

Comment: are malwarebytes and avira the only AV on the computer? If so exit before trying another extension install.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove yesterday he  installed avira. before that it was  ms defender. exit what

Comment: exit the AV (antivirus) software installed on the computer.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove dont think it matters but I will let him know and report back

Comment: antivirus programs are known to block many things, web downloads one of them.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove you have a good point. Will asl him to try